# How to not use strings as method parameters in c#

Tags: c#

I have a few methods like the following

```cs
public static string RequestEntry (string name)
{
    if (name == "John" || name == "Bob" || name == "Ken")
        return $"Hello {name}, you may enter";
    return $"Get out of here {name}, no one like you!";
}
    
public static string Kiddify (string name)
{
    if (name == "John" || name == "Bob" || name == "Ken")
        return $"{name}{name[^1]}y";
    return $"Get out of here {name}, no one like you!";
}
```

*Note: These are only meant to demonstrate a concept and not the purposes of my real methods. My real methods have their own isolated functionality.)*

My issues with this is:

1. I am a very bad typer/speller and will most likely mistype the string that pass into this method, which could introduce bugs.
2. I don't want there to be a default case, because I have specific input string I want to work with.
3. Programming is a hobby. I will sometimes go weeks without having time to code and remembering the valid strings I can pass is highly unlikely.

So, I thought to use an `enum`

```cs
public enum Name{
    John,
    Bob,
    Ken
}
```

and implement the methods as follows

```cs
public static string RequestEntry (Name name)
{
    string sName = name switch
    {
        Name.John => "John",
        Name.Bob => "Bob",
        Name.Ken => "Ken",  
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };

    return $"Hello {sName}, you may enter";
}
    
public static string Kiddify (Name name)
{
    return name switch
    {
        Name.John => "Johnny",
        Name.Bob => "Bobby",
        Name.Ken => "Kenny",    
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
}
```

I feel like this would be pretty common practice, and it solves all my above issues. Now my issue is that modifying `Names` will mean I also have to modify my class methods to deal with the changes.

And finally, we get to the question. Is there another way I do this?

I considered using reflection and attributes to assign string values to the different names in the `enum`, but I would have to assign a different string attribute for each use case. I don't like that idea and don't like using reflection if at all possible.

Comment: Side note: `NotImplementedException` is not appropriate in these cases. It means that the method is not implemented, and clearly you've implemented it `ArgumentException` (or something derived from it) is appropriate because the caller provided an argument that is not valid, which you've determined in this case by first handling all valid inputs first, and you need to indicate the name of the parameter and what's wrong with it.

Comment: Typically this wouldn't be coded like this in a real life scenario. But for the sake of the example you could take advantage of `Attributes`. You can create a custom attribute attach to each `Enum` value that would contain the text value you want (an possibly more informations) and retrieve it from the `Enum` parameter by reflection.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you for that. I wanted to get this out before I go to work and couldn't think of an appropriate exception in a hurry.

Comment: @Franck I'm sorry if I didn't make this clear, but I don't want to use reflection. Thank you anyway for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your inputs, but (as is sometimes the case) about an hour after I posted the question, I thought of a solution that would work for me.

```cs
using System;

public class Names
{
    public string adultName;
    public string kidName;
    
    
    public static Names John = new Names 
    {
        adultName = "John",
        kidName = "Johnny"
    };
    
    public static Names Bob = new Names 
    {
        adultName = "Bob",
        kidName = "Bobby"
    };
    
    public static Names Ken = new Names 
    {
        adultName = "Ken",
        kidName = "Kenny"
    };
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RequestEntry(Names.John));
        Console.WriteLine(Kiddify(Names.Bob));
    }
    
    public static string RequestEntry (Names name)
    {
        return $"Hello {name.adultName}, you may enter";
    }
    
    public static string Kiddify (Names name)
    {
        return name.kidName;
    }
}
```

What do you all think?

Answer (score 2):

Why not organize names into a *collection*? For instance

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> s_Names = new() {
  "John", "Bob", "Ken"
};

public static string RequestEntry (string name) =>
  s_Names.Contains(name)
    ? $"Hello {name}, you may enter"
    : $"Get out of here {name}, no one like you!";
```

Comment: I like this approach over using switches, but it still requires me to pass a string. And for that reason, I'm out. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Sorry of that sounded rude. At the time it was funny to me, but now I think it makes me sound like an ass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Enum.ToString` method to get the string `"John"` from an enum. For example:

```
Names.John.ToString()
```

You can use your `Kiddify` method on this string afterwards.

(The opposite is `Enum.TryParse` which will get the `enum` value from a `string`. )

Comment: Afaik ```ToString()``` uses reflection, which I don't want.